# Creating an specific colourmap in matlab/python

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, color-scheme, colormap

Not sure where is the best place to ask this question but here it goes:

Through a malfunction of my pc screen I got a plot I'd made ages ago, using matlab but works fine in python as well, to go from your regular 'hot' colormap to something completely different as shown in the pic below:

[image]

Top part is the original hot and bottom is the 'malfunction' going from dark blue to white-ish from bright pink

Does anyone know how to get that done intentionally?

As it turned out, I like that colour scheme much better, but not sure how/were to get it right.

Comment: What colormap do you want to get? The blue/pink/white one, or a colormap that merges that with the red/yellow/white one?

Comment: Well, MATLAB already provide a tool to define and tune your own custom colormap. Intuitively enough, it's called [`Colormap Editor`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormapeditor.html)

Comment: @Hoki intuitively enough that work to modify a pre-existing colourmap, not to re-set it completely

Comment: @LuisMendo I want to get the blue/pink/white... as stated in the question.

Comment: @Mac The questio currently states _how to get that done intentionally_. It was not clear what the pronoun _that_ referred to

Comment: In addition to defining a cutom colormap you also need to change the  value of the  top part of the image.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-colors-colormap-manipulation-py

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A colormap is just a 3-column matrix where each row defines a color. Specifically, the columns define the R, G, B components respectively. Therefore, you can create colormaps manually.

For example, a colormap what goes from blue to white can be produced by setting the B component to 1 and letting the other two range from 0 to 1:

```
cmap = [linspace(0,1,256).' linspace(0,1,256).' ones(256,1)];
colormap(cmap)
colorbar('horizontal')
```

[image]

Something closer to your blue/pink/white example can be achieved by rearraging the columns of the `hot` colormap:

```
cmap = hot(256);
cmap = cmap(:,[2 3 1]);
colormap(cmap),
colorbar('horizontal')
```

[image]

Many nice colormaps can be produced from the `BrewerMap` function, available on [File Exchange](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45208-colorbrewer-attractive-and-distinctive-colormaps) or [GitHub](https://github.com/DrosteEffect/BrewerMap).

A problem with manually generated colormaps is that they are not [perceptually uniform](https://peterkovesi.com/projects/colourmaps/) in general. In contrast, many of Matlab's default colormaps like `parula`, or Python's like `magma`, are perceptually uniform. Here's a [discussion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2014/10/20/a-new-colormap-for-matlab-part-2-troubles-with-rainbows/) about uniform and non-uniform colormaps, focused on `parula`. You can use Python's colormaps in Matlab with this [File Exchange function](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/51986-perceptually-uniform-colormaps) by Ander Biguri.

Here are two examples with Matlab's `parula` and Python's `plasma`. In either of them, equal increments along the horizontal axis roughly correspond to a similar perception of "color change".

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the comments. Yeah, another problem with the map I wanted, which you just gave me a way to make it, is that is not friendly to colour-blindness. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your screen simply inverted the colours. If you want to invert a colormap in MATLAB, you can do this fairly simply by doing the following:

```matlab
colormap(1-hot);
```

which will change the reds in the hot map to blues, and the blacks to whites. If you would rather the other way around (i.e., red -> white, black -> blue) you can do this:

```matlab
colormap(1-flipud(hot));
```

This should work for any colormap.

Comment: That doesn't produce pink, does it?

Comment: I have no idea. I can't see any pink in the original plot, but I'm colourblind so that might be why.

Comment: @LuisMendo It doesn't no! That will be the same as simply inverting the colours, which I tried with paint... doesn't give pink =(.

Comment: @MrAzzaman, Yeah, I don't think is a great map for colourblind, unfortunately. Hadn't thought of that.... Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: You could set the colormap using the invert method I mentioned, then add in pink using the colormap editor mentioned by Hoki.